# Export Quickbooks IIF from command line

Tags: quickbooks

Is there a method of exporting a company file to IIF from the command line in QuickBooks?  I'm running QuickBooks Enterprise 9.0 Professional Services Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You shouldn't be using IIF files anyway, they are deprecated and buggy (and have been for many years now).

You should look into using the QuickBooks SDK, or IPP/IDS (if it's a SaaS application).

See also:
 [How can I integrate my application with QuickBooks?](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_methods)